# How to integrate bing_translator-gem into rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, translation

I'm trying to make a simple translation forum using Rails 4 and relrod's bing_translator gem.
I'm very much a rookie but have managed to get a site working with posts, comments, voting of comments, but am having difficulty making the translator part work. When I run the following code in the console, the app works and translates as described by the gem documentation.

```
translator = BingTranslator.new('#####', '##########')
translated = translator.translate('this is what's being translated', :to => 'es')
```

What i cannot figure out though is how I could go about integrating this into my show page? @post.translation is supposed to be translated and placed into @post.translated?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users
get 'welcome/index'
  resources :posts do
   post 'translated'
  resources :comments do
    member do
      post 'vote_up'
    end
  end
end
root "welcome#index"
end
```

show.html.haml

```
#post_show
    %h1= @post.title
    %p.username
        Posted by
        = @post.user.name
        about
        = time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at)
    %p
        Task : 
        %br
        =@post.task
    %p
        Translation :
        %br
        =@post.translation
        %br
        =@post.translated
```

post.rb

```
    def translate
        @post= Post.find(params[:id])
        translator = BingTranslator.new('######', '########')
        @post.translated = translator.translate(@post.translated, :from => 'en', :to => 'fr')

    end
```

Comment: where this instance variable is set @post.translation?
could you include the entire post model?

Comment: In the database, the posts have a title, a task, a translation field, and a translated field

create "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "task"
    t.text     "translation"
    t.text     "translated"
  end